# EntityFramework PostgreSQL GIST index for geography column

Tags: entity-framework-core, postgis, npgsql

I'm trying to create a index, like this one:

```
CREATE INDEX example1_gpx ON example1 USING GIST (geography(geomcol));
```

Using EF codefirst, I did this on codefirst:

```
    builder.HasIndex(x => new
        {
            x.GeoLocation
        })
        .HasMethod("GIST");
```

but I can't specify that it's a column of type geography.

How I can create this index using CodeFirst ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index above seems to apply a `geography()` conversion to a `geometry` column; if so, it's an expression index (as opposed to a simple index over a column). The Npgsql EF Core provider doesn't currently support modeling expression indexes ([see this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/119)), but you can always use [raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#adding-raw-sql) to create the index in migrations.

However, I'd recommend thinking why you're converting a `geometry` column into `geography` in an expression index; you may want to consider making your column `geography` instead. Another option is to have an additional generated column of type `geography` alongside the `geometry` column.